# Create View inner join error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm creating a view and using inner join and receiving the following error:

```
ORA-00904: "B"."CUSTOMERNO": invalid identifier
```

This is the code I'm working with to create view and inner join

```
CREATE VIEW RentalInfoOct
(branch_no, branch_name, customer_no)
AS
SELECT b.branchNo, b.branchName, b.customerNo, c.customerNo
FROM branch b
INNER JOIN 
customer c
ON b.customerNo = c.customerNo
```

Here are the create table commands as well.

```
CREATE TABLE Branch
(
branchNo    SMALLINT    NOT NULL,
branchName  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
branchAddress   VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (BranchNo)
);  

CREATE TABLE Customer
(
customerNo      SMALLINT    NOT NULL,
customerName        VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
customerAddress     VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
customerTel         VARCHAR(10),
PRIMARY KEY (CustomerNo)
);
```

Comment: There is no customerNo column on the Branch table.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW RentalInfoOct
(branch_no, branch_name, customer_no)
AS
SELECT b.branchNo, b.branchName, b.customerNo, c.customerNo
```

You specify 3 columns for the view, but you select 4 columns in SELECT